# height 100% with multiple columns not working

Tags: jquery, html, css

I want to do something seemingly simple. I want two columns on the page that have a width of 50% each and a height of 100% so they fill the screen completely. I want them side by side so they divide the screen in half. However, no matter what I do for some reason, they refuse to fill the page and float with each other.

I tried getting around it using jQuery but if the window is resized then the columns no longer fill the page. I tried searching around but nothing offers a solution to multiple columns. I've seen this done on many websites and can't figure it out. Is there a way to do it with pure CSS or more efficient jQuery?

http://jsfiddle.net/nFeh8/1/

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="on"> 
        <button type="button" class="btn-on">
            on
        </button>
    </div>

        <div class="off">
        <button type="button" class="btn-off">
            off
        </button>
    </div>

</div>
```

.

```
html {
    height: 100%;
}

container {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.on {
    width: 50%;
   height: 100%; 
    background-color: #FEE;
    float: left; 
}

.off {
    width: 50%;
   height: 100%;
    background-color: #666;
    float: left;       
}

.btn-off {
    position: relative;
}
```

.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var height = $(window).height();
    $('.on').css({'height':height + 'px'});
    $('.off').css({'height':height + 'px'});
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you use div's styled as a table to realize it. This is the most easy and comprehensible approach. Try it like this:

CSS:

```
html,body {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
}

.div-table {
    display:table;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}

.div-table-row {
    display:table-row;
}

.div-table-cell {
    display:table-cell;
    width:50%;
    height:100%;
}

/* only for showing you the columns */

.div-table-cell:nth-child(1) {
    background-color:red;
}

.div-table-cell:nth-child(2) {
    background-color:green;
}
```

And HTML:

```
<div class="div-table">
    <div class="div-table-row">
        <div class="div-table-cell"></div>
        <div class="div-table-cell"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Working JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/T9BsG/1/

Advantages are: no JS used (keeps Site lean), no float:left; used (leads sometimes to unpredictable results)

Comment: I dread using tables but this seems to be the best approach without using js so far. Thank you

Comment: Actually you aren't using tables, but only div's acting like tables. There's an important difference ;-)

Answer (score 1):

With jQuery you can call the same declarations on document ready as well as window resize:

```
var blockAdj = function () {
    var height = $(window).height();
    $('.on').css({'height':height + 'px'});
    $('.off').css({'height':height + 'px'});
};

$(document).ready(blockAdj);
$(window).resize(blockAdj);
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/effone/nFeh8/6/

% value with height? << I have a huge doubt about it ...

Comment: This works well enough but is it efficient to use jQuery instead of just CSS for something like this?

Comment: As I said I have faced issues with % value in height earlier; if you at all wanna go with CSS only the solution I can think of is display: table-cell;

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if this will work for you, but...

```
.on {
    width: 50%;
    height: 100%; 
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    background-color: #FEE;
}

.off {
    width: 50%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 50%;
    background-color: #666;      
}
```

You don't really even need the container with this.

Answer (score 0):

For both classes the code below will work. the container that sets on the right needs to be and position of absolute so no matter what is on the page it sets exactly where you tell it to. 
     `

```
 .on{
   position:absolute;
   width: 50%;
   height:100%
 }
 .off{
   position:absolute;
   left:50%;
   height:100%;
 } 
 `
```

add in any other attributes you want.

Answer (score 0):

I am not an experienced programmer, but recently when i had a similar problem, i had to divide  width of a wrapping container into 4 blocks. I ran into the same preoblem where the 4th block would slide down below block 1. I had given width:25% in my css. when I changed it to 24% the blocks lined up proper.  Its the margin that was throwing the whole thing off so I accounted 1% towards the margin and padding . Hope this is helpful

Comment: reducing % value is a poor effort to adjust through CSS. the right way to use is: box-sizing: border-box;   See here: http://css-tricks.com/examples/BoxSizing/

Answer (score 0):

You absolutely do not need jquery or tables (or table display types) for this.  Two things:

One: you need to give the body element a height as well.  Essentially, everything between your target element and the window (or whatever your target container might be) needs a height.

`html, body {
    height: 100%;
}`

Two: you want to target the div with the class of "container", not an element named container.  Thus add a period:

`.container {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}`

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/nFeh8/7/